# Combining mandatory and optional args with subcommands

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am struggling with command-line parsing and argparse, how to handle global variables, subcommands and optional params to these subcommands

I'm writting a python3 wrapper around python-libvirt to manage my VMs. The wrapper will handle creation, removal, stop/start, snapshots, etc.

A partial list of the options follows, that shows the different ways to pass params to my script:

```
# Connection option for all commands:
# ---
# vmman.py [-c hypervisor] (defaults to qemu:///system)

# Generic VM commands:
# ---
# vmman.py show : list all vms, with their state
# vmman.py {up|down|reboot|rm} domain : boots, shuts down, reboots 
or deletes the domain

# Snapshot management:
# ---
# vmman.py lssnap domain : list snapshots attached to domain
# vmman.py snaprev domain [snapsname] : reverts domain to latest 
snapshot or to snapname

# Resource management:
# ---
# vmman.py domain resdel [disk name] [net iface]
```

And then some code used to test the first subcommand :

```
def setConnectionString(args):
    print('Arg = %s' % args.cstring)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parserConnect = subparsers.add_parser('ConnectionURI')
parserConnect.set_defaults(func=setConnectionString)
parserConnect.add_argument('-c', '--connect', dest='host')

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
print("COMPLETED")
```

Now, the argparse() doc on docs.python.org is dense and a bit confusing of a python newbie as I am... I would have expected the output to be something like:

```
`Arg = oslo`
```

What I get is :

```
[10:21:40|jfgratton@bergen:kvmman.py]: ./argstest.py -c oslo
usage: argstest.py [-h] {ConnectionURI} ...
argstest.py: error: invalid choice: 'connectionURI' (choose from 'ConnectionURI')
```

I obviously miss something, and I'm only testing the one I thought would be the easiest of the lot (global param); haven't even figured yet on how to handle optional subparams and all.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense; calling './argstest.py -c oslo' gives a different error output ...

Comment: Given this parser, the command line should be `./argstest.py ConnectionURI -c oslo`.  You must include one of the strings defined by a `add_parser` command.  And your function should look for a `args.connect` attribute.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the `setdefaults` example from https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands, package that in a script, and test it.  Once you understand how it's working, then adapted it to your case.  I'd also suggest including a `print(args)` statement so you see exactly what the `parse_args()` command produces.

Answer (score 0):

Your error output lists 'connectionURI' with lowercase 'c' as invalid choice, while it also says "choose from 'ConnectionURI'" with capital letter 'C'.

Fix: Call your test with:

./argstest.py ConnectionURI oslo

Maybe you should start simple (without subparsers) and build from there:

```
import argparse

def setConnectionString(hostname):
    print('Arg = {}'.format(hostname))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='python3 wrapper around python-libvirt to manage VMs')
parser.add_argument('hostname')

args = parser.parse_args()
setConnectionString(args.hostname)

print("COMPLETED")
```

Comment: True, the edit does not make sense, I originally pasted the wrong attempt I did, and mis-edited my OP.

Here's the real output (just attempted again):
`[12:09:21|jfgratton@bergen:kvmman.py]: ./argstest.py -c oslo
usage: argstest.py [-h] {ConnectionURI} ...
argstest.py: error: invalid choice: 'oslo' (choose from 'ConnectionURI')`

Comment: `[12:09:25|jfgratton@bergen:kvmman.py]: ./argstest.py ConnectionURI oslo
usage: argstest.py [-h] {ConnectionURI} ...
argstest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: oslo`

Comment: The second error is because you have not added an argument for oslo: `parser.add_argument('place')`.

Comment: Ok, I agree that I might need a bit of hand-holding here, and that I wasn't clear:
oslo can be replaced with any value (oslo is the hypervisor's hostname; I have 3 of these). I'll look "place" up.

I'm aware that my OP is not totally clear. I'm not real familiar with StackOverflow's way of posting. Apologies.

Comment: That was just a random name because I had no idea what you were talking about; use `parser.add_argument('hostname')` then. Argparse expects you to `.add_argument()` for every different argument you need.

Comment: Well, I still get the same error:  

`[14:18:09|jfgratton@bergen:kvmman.py]: ./argstest.py -c oslo
usage: argstest.py [-h] {connectURI} ...
argstest.py: error: invalid choice: 'oslo' (choose from 'connectURI')
`

And that is, once I've added `parserConnect.add_argument('hostname')`